# How to show blank page(not redirect) when other use my website in the frame set?

Tags: javascript, security

I have found enough solution that redirect to the website in the frame. But the solution I want is just to show blank in the frame.

Note: I already know the solution by using below mentioned script on the website

```
if(top.location != location){
    top.location.href = document.location.href;
}
```

Also .htaccess option doesn't look fit for me (We use IIS)

Please don't mark it as duplication to "How to stop my website being framed by other?" as I am looking for different solution than redirect.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the X-Frame-Options response header to your page. This will prevent browsers from loading the page in the page in a frame. There are 2 relevant values that you could set it to, either SAMEORIGIN, or DENY. Setting it to DENY will prevent the browser from ever rendering it in a frame. On the other hand, setting it to SAMEORIGIN will only allow it to be framed from the current domain.

Look at the response headers returned by stackoverflow.com. One of them is:

`X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`

That means that if you tried to frame stackoverflow.com on your own domain, the browser wouldn't load it.

To set it in IIS, you would add something similar to the following to your configuration file.

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="DENY" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your **overall** goal is, and how restrictive you want to be.

You could:

1. Frame bust.
2. Check the referrer and refuse to allow any meaningful content from your site to be displayed outside the navigation paths you want used within your site.
3. It seems you are saying that you are aware of how to redirect to a web page from within the frame.  If you don't wish to keep a "blank page" around and redirect to that when someone tries to present something from your site within a frame, you could manipulate the DOM, choose not to display the normal content of the page, instead present a blank DIV.
4. Although it could be less definite than manipulating the DOM/etc. with whatever scripting can be used within the browser the User has chosen, you could try to dynamically set an overarching CSS style so that any attempt to display anything from your site is not physically seen by anyone.